# I don't know what candy to use for gingerbread windows

Tags: gingerbread

I am looking for a candy to use for windows.What should I use!

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Could you give us a bit more information? What size are the windows? Do you have particular colors you are interested in or do you want them to be transparent? Are you considering making them yourself? Please [edit] your question to help us help you better!

Answer (score 5):

Hard Candy would be your best bet, [like this recipe](http://www.lorannoils.com/hard-candy-recipe), if you want to make 'custom' windows. The presence and concentration of food coloring can get you from 'clearish' to solid colors. If you want to go 'off the shelf' There are a variety of lollipops that are translucent which might give you a nice effect.

If you want to get 'real fancy' break up some Jolly Ranchers and use a little frosting to go "stained glass" :o)